# Show image if word is Not in the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show an image if the URL doesn't have the word "Diecut" and if the URL has the word Diecut, the image should be hidden.

```
<img id="dieCutFallback" src="images/Die-Cut-Banner-2.jpg" style="display:none;"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("Diecut") != -1) {
   $("#dieCutFallback").show();
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? (There are ways it could be improved, but it looks like it should function as intended)

Comment: @DBS Its the opposite. The image is hidden when the URL doesn't contain the word Diecut. I need the image to show when the URL doesn't contain the word Diecut.

Comment: Maybe try lowercasing Diecut to diecut. Can you share your URL for which you expect this to work?

Comment: If you want to invert it, surely just switching from `!=` to `==` (or better, `===`) will do the trick?

Comment: Then negate the condition in if ??? What you have now is `if(Diecut is found) show` indexOf returns -1 if it doesn't find the string, so when it's found, the value is not -1, thus the condition is true...

Comment: I know this question is tagged as `javascript` but this can be done with CSS only.
`#dieCutFallback[src*=Diecut] {display: none}`